# Bound on $f_n'$ implies uniform convergence of $f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions that converge pointwise to a function $f$.

Suppose I know that $|f_n'(x)| \leq C(x)$ where the constant doesn't depend on $n$. How do I conclude that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets?

Comment: I think you need additional conditions on $C(x)$, such as $C$ is continuous. In this case, you can use the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks. I got it now but just one problem: Given a compact set $K$ I can find a sequence $f_n$ that converges uniformly in $K$. But how do I get a single sequence that converges uniformly for every compact set $K$?

Comment: Given that $C$ is continuous wrt. $x$. But the bound $|C(x)| \leq a $may depend on the endpoints of the compact interval.

Comment: Given $K$, show that every subsequence of $(f_n)$  has a further subsequence that converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$. This will imply $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I think you misunderstand my question. I meant that given $K$, we know there is a sequence $f_n^K$ depending on $K$ in some way that uniformly converges in $K$. But I would like a single sequence $f_n$ such that for *all* compact $K$, $f_n$ converges uniformly in $K$. I hope I did not misunderstand your comment.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. I presume you start with a given sequence $(f_n)$ and wish to show that it converges uniformly to $f$ on any compact set.  So fix $K$ compact. By A-A, every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$. So $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$. Your "single sequence" is just $(f_n)$.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry and thanks for the help!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I give an example to show that  the bound $|f_n'(x)| \leq C(x)$, with some finite-valued   $C(x)$, is not sufficient to obtain uniform convergence. Example: let 
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1-\cos nx, \quad & 0\le x\le 2\pi/n \\ 0  \quad & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
We have $f_n\to 0$ pointwise. Also, 
$$f_n'(x) = \begin{cases} n\sin nx, \quad & 0\le x\le 2\pi/n \\ 0  \quad & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
satisfies $f_n'\to 0$ pointwise. Since every convergent sequence is bounded, it follows that $\sup_n |f_n'(x)|$ is finite  at every point. Yet, the convergence $f_n\to 0$ is not uniform since $f_n(\pi/n)=2$.

If you assume that $C$ is bounded on every compact subset (which is the case when $C$ is continuous), then the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem applies, as David Mitra described:

> you start with a given sequence $(f_n)$ and wish to show that it converges uniformly to $f$ on any compact set.  So fix $K$ compact. By  the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$. So $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $K$.